# Cannot connect to Ubuntu Samba from Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, server-message-block

I setup Samba on a Ubuntu 22.02 server. I cannot access the shared with Windows but I can with Linux. Ports 139 and 445 are open and listening on loopback and lan interface. I even made the share public to test it without credentials and no connection. I feel like I'm missing something. I can ping the server from the windows PC. I included the smb.conf below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> [global]
>
> ```
>    workgroup = WORKGROUP
>    netbios name = WORKGROUP
>    passdb backend = smbpasswd
>    security = user
>    client min protocol = NT1
>    server min protocol = NT1
>
>    server string = %h server
>    server role = standalone server
>    interfaces = lo bond0
>    bind interfaces only = yes
>    disable netbios = yes
>    smb ports = 445, 139
>    log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log.%m
>    max log size = 10000
>    log level = 3 passdb:5 auth:5
> ```
>
> ===== Share Definitions =====
>
> [filearchive]
>
> ```
>    path = /share/archive/filearchive
>    browseable = yes
>    read only = no
>    force create mode = 0660
>    force create mode = 2770
>    valid users = filebackupuser, root
>    public = yes
> ```

Comment: What versions of Windows are you using ?

Comment: Windows 10. I even lowered the protocol to SMBv1 for both server and client and no connection.